# good PHP validation libraries

Tags: php, validation, email, input

I'm trying to find a list of good validation libraries (phone, email, etc.) that are constantly being maintained. I use PHP and am open to libraries from frameworks, but if you recommend a library from a framework, please say whether it allows you to use it without the framework itself?

Comment: The filter extension is included by default with PHP: http://php.net/filter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could give a go to `Zend_Validate`

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.introduction.html

With the Zend framework, you can choose to use whichever part of the framework you like. If you go for very basic validation, it can be as simple as static calls to predefined methods such as:

```
if (Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
    // Yes, email appears to be valid
}
```

Otherwise you also have the option of building custom validators of your own design.

Comment: I really like Zend_Validate, and also the feature for chain Validation and return an array of validation messages.

Comment: Another article over http://websec.io/2013/12/31/Input-Filtering-Validation-Aura-Filter.html

Answer (score 4):

Whats wrong with [filter_var](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_filter_var.asp)?

Comment: that it is not available on versions before 5.2

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Respect\Validation](https://github.com/Respect/Validation) in my lots of projects and trust me it's worth using. It provides features like Complex (custom) rules, Customizable & iterable exceptions and 80 (fully tested) validators.

i.e. numeric validation:

```
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
$number = 123;
v::numeric()->validate($number); //true
```

i.e. chained validation:

```
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;
$usernameValidator = v::alnum()->noWhitespace()->length(1,15);
$usernameValidator->validate('alganet'); //true
```

Read Full [Documentation here.](http://documentup.com/Respect/Validation/)

Fork on [Github here.](https://github.com/Respect/Validation)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the PEAR library Validate [here](http://pear.php.net/package/Validate).

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon https://github.com/vlucas/valitron

Seems pretty simple to use and I like how its designed to be dependency free